# For loop with enumerate iterates 4 times, but only 1 dataframe is written to Excel instead of 4 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I have been struggling with this code all day. During each run of the loop, a table is read from a different MS Word file. The table is copied to a dataframe and then it is copied to a row in an Excel file.

With each subsequent run of the for-loop, the Excel row is incremented so the new dataframe can be written to a new row, but after the file executes only one row is showing a dataframe.

When I print(tfile), I get the following .. ('CIV-ASCS-016_TRS.docx', 'CIV-ASCS-018_TRS .docx', 'CIV-ASCS-020_TRS.docx', 'CIV-ASCS-021_TRS .docx') This proves that loop ran 4 times based on 4 files in the directory. I set the initial row pos to 0 outside of the for-loop.

Note: I am not showing any lines of code with regards to importing the necessary libraries.

```
files = glob('*.docx')
pos = 1

for i, wfile in enumerate(files[:1]):

  document = Document(wfile)

  table = document.tables[0]
  data = []
  keys = {}

  for j, row in enumerate(table.rows):
     text = (cell.text for cell in row.cells)
     if j == 0:
            keys = tuple(text)
            continue

     row_data = dict(zip(keys, text))
     data.append(row_data)

     tfile = tuple(files)

  df = pd.DataFrame(data)
  df.loc[-1] = [wfile, 'Test Case ID']   
  df.index = df.index + 1  # shifting index
  df = df.sort_index()  # sorting by index

  df1 = df.rename(index=str, columns={"Test Case ID": "TC Attributes"})

  df21 = df1.drop(columns = ['TC Attributes'])
  df3 = df21.T

# read the existing sheets so that openpyxl won't create a new one later
  book = load_workbook('test.xlsx')
  writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') 
  writer.book = book
  writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
  df3.to_excel(writer, 'sheet7', header = False, index = False, \
             startrow = pos)
  pos += 1

  writer.save()
```

Comment: Finally!!!!! I fixed the problem. The enumerate should have begun at 4 instead of -1. There are 4 files in the directory to be read. With enumerate set to -1, only one file was being read. Setting enumerate to -1 was recommended to me by someone. If someone could explain why -1 could have been incorrectly recommended, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Where is the -1 in your code above?

Comment: Sorry about that, I should  have been more clear. It was the third line of code I was referring to:
for i, wfile in enumerate(files[:1]): 
I changed the enumerate value from -1 and then to 1, then finally figured out that settings it to 4 worked as I had 4 files to be read. The -1 setting was recommended from an example i found from a website for doing the exact same thing I wanted to do.